# How do db.FirstOrCreate and db.Where().FirstOrCreate() differ?

Tags: go, go-gorm

```golang
// Unfound
db.FirstOrCreate(&user, User{Name: "non_existing"})
//// INSERT INTO "users" (name) VALUES ("non_existing");
//// user -> User{Id: 112, Name: "non_existing"}
// Found
db.Where(User{Name: "Jinzhu"}).FirstOrCreate(&user)
//// user -> User{Id: 111, Name: "Jinzhu"}
```

Hi, I read the documentation of `gorm`, but I couldn't spot the difference between both of them.
Can someone explain

[Documentation](http://gorm.io/docs/query.html#FirstOrCreate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gorm documentation is not comprehensive and a bit cryptic. To my understandings, there is no difference between using explicit where and using where inside `FirstOrCreate`. The point of this example is to show that you can use either way.

If the object is not there (`"non_existing`" case) then it'll execute an INSERT, otherwise it would not.